# Do action after foreach and dispatch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do an action AFTER the foreach and my dispatches. In the for loop when i come across one type of enum, the showAlert will get YES. For showing the allert after all the tasks and loops.

I've tried it, but the allert show up already when the dispatch_sync is still going. How can i solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
Problem overview: The problem is then that the UIAlertView already comes up before the loops are done, so i don't have any value set (For loop does this of my randomInt) and my AlertView takes this int. So That's why i want to wait until all loops/foreach are done in the method and then let the UIAlertView come up, so i have 100% the integer that i needed.

Code:

```
-(void)animateRolling{

    [[self firstLabelOutlet] setHidden:YES];

    long index;
    int randomIndex;
    __block BOOL showAllert = NO;

    randomIndex = arc4random() % 20;

    if (randomIndex == 8) {
        [self showAd];
    }

    for(detailDice* cell in [[self dobbelstenenCollection] visibleCells]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self dobbelstenenCollection] indexPathForCell:cell];

        if ([arrayDobbel count] >= 3) {
            index = 2 * indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
        }else{
            index = 1 * indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
        }

        if ([cell isHidden]) {
            [cell setHidden:NO];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ([[arrayDobbel objectAtIndex:index] diceSoort] == ENUMHoelangDobbel) {

                        randomInt = ((arc4random() % ([self maxduration] - 1 + 1 )) + 1.0);
                        [[cell detaildiceLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds \n %i", (int)randomInt]];

                        showAllert = YES;

                    }else if ([[arrayDobbel objectAtIndex:index] diceSoort] == ENUMOgen){

                        [[cell detailDiceImage] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", ( (arc4random() % (6-1+1)) + 1 )]]];

                    }else{
                        [[cell detaildiceLabel] setText: [[arrayDobbel objectAtIndex:index] returnRandomOptie]];
                    }

                });
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
            }
        });
    }

    if (showAllert) {
        [self showDurationAlert];
    }
}
```

Kind Regards!

Comment: You want to call the alert only once?

Comment: Try to use NSOperationQueue

Comment: @bsarr007 Yeah only once in that method. And is getting called each time the main method is called.

Comment: I don't really know what you try to do but you can show it inside the second dispatch_async after the last block is executed, be sure call it once.

Comment: What is the point of this combination of dispatches? You are giving background threads jobs to do nothing but wait for main thread to do something and sleep. Why not dispatch those jobs to the main thread directly?

Comment: @hamstergene I need to do it on this way for updating my labels with a for loop. Else the label will update on the last cycle of the for loop when the job is done. I needed to set the label each cycle so the user get the look something is changing.

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide a concise and comprehensive example where you show *what* you are trying to accomplish. Looking at your code, it's hard to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Oke yeah sorry for that. So people throw a couple of dices, and if one of the dices has the ENUMhoelang (that's a duration dice). there will come up an UIAlertView for the user to choose for throw again, or start timer. With this method it animates the throwing labels that the text changes fast with the for loop.

Comment: @Kets With "concise and comprehensive" I really mean a *concise* and possibly abstract and contrived description of your *core* problem. I would guess it's irrelevant whether there are dices, enums and UIAlertViews. Maybe it's a loop executing methods on the main thread with a delay?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Sorry, didn't realize that you meant that because I'm dutch. This method is called from a Push on the screen or Shake with the Device. The problem is then that the UIAlertView already comes up before the loops are done, so i don't have any value set (For loop does this of my randomInt) and my AlertView takes this int. So That's why i want to wait until all loops/foreach are done in the method and then let the UIAlertView come up, so i have 100% the integer that i needed. Is this the concise description you wanted ? This is basically the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create group with `dispatch_group_create`.

Use `dispatch_group_async` instead `dispatch_async`.

And path yours block, that should be performed after foreach and dispatch in `dispatch_group_notify`.

All is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refactor your code through making `animateRolling` an *asynchronous* method, and the invocation of `showDurationAlert` a "continuation":

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(BOOL showAlert);

-(void)animateRollingWithCompletion:(completion_t)completion;
```

and use it as follows:

```
[self animateRollingWithCompletion:^(BOOL showAlert){
    if (showAlert) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self showDurationAlert];
        });
    }
}];
```

I would also suggest to utilize a `NSTimer` or better a dispatch timer (dispatch_source_t) to implement the method `animateRollingWithCompletion`.

You can create and use dispatch timer as follows:

```
// Create a timer:
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);

// Define the handler block:
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    ...
});

// Start the timer (here, as a one shot timer):
uint64_t leeway = 0; // allowed maximum delay
uint64_t interval = delay_in_secs * NSEC_PER_SEC;
dispatch_source_set_timer(
     timer, 
     dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval), // time *when* to start
     DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER,   // interval, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER for "one shot"
     leeway                   // maximum allowed delay
);
dispatch_resume(timer);

// Cancel a timer:
dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
```

In order to start a periodic timer whose handler will be called at the *start* of each period, you might write:

```
dispatch_source_set_timer(
     timer, 
     dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0),
     interval, 
     leeway);
dispatch_resume(timer);
```

With this knowledge, I think it's possible to craft a handler block, which is driven by a periodic timer. The block retrieves parameters form an array and executes your core methods (e.g. setting up the cells) on the main thread.

When all parameters have been retrieved and the work has been finished, the block may call dispatch_after() with the specified interval (or test for the "finished" condition at the start of a new period) which eventually calls the completion block provided as parameter in method `animateRollingWithCompletion` and defined by the call-site (which in turn brings up the Alert View).